# Button not where supposed to be

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have this code:

```
public static final String DEFAULT_TITLE = "Login";

public static final String USERNAME_LABEL_DEFAULT_TEXT = "Username: ";
public static final String PASSWORD_LABEL_TEXT = "Password: ";

public static final String DEFAULT_LOGIN_TEXT = "Login";
public static final String CANCEL_TEXT = "Cancel";

public static final boolean DEFAULT_HAS_CANCEL = true;
public static final boolean DEFAULT_CAN_CLOSE = true;

private static final Insets MAIN_PANE_PADDING = new Insets(10);
private static final int MAIN_PANE_GAP = 10;
private static final int BUTTON_PREF_WIDTH = 60;
private static final int BUTTON_PANE_SPACING = 10;

private static final boolean IS_RESIZABLE = false;

private static final ColumnConstraints COL_1_CONSTRAINS = new ColumnConstraints(
        70);
private static final ColumnConstraints COL_2_CONSTRAINS = new ColumnConstraints(
        200);

private static String username = null;
private static char[] password = null;

public static UserInfo showLoginPane() {
    return showLoginPane(DEFAULT_TITLE);
}

public static UserInfo showLoginPane(String title) {
    return showLoginPane(title, USERNAME_LABEL_DEFAULT_TEXT);
}

public static UserInfo showLoginPane(String title,
        String usernameLabelText) {
    return showLoginPane(title, usernameLabelText, DEFAULT_LOGIN_TEXT);
}

public static UserInfo showLoginPane(String title,
        String usernameLabelText, String loginText) {
    return showLoginPane(title, usernameLabelText, loginText, DEFAULT_HAS_CANCEL, DEFAULT_CAN_CLOSE);
}

public static UserInfo showLoginPane(String title,
        String usernameLabelText, String loginText, boolean hasCancel,
        boolean canClose) {

    Stage stage = new Stage();

    GridPane mainPane = new GridPane();
    mainPane.setPadding(MAIN_PANE_PADDING);
    mainPane.setHgap(MAIN_PANE_GAP);
    mainPane.setVgap(MAIN_PANE_GAP);
    mainPane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(COL_1_CONSTRAINS,
            COL_2_CONSTRAINS);

    Label userLabel = new Label(usernameLabelText);
    GridPane.setHalignment(userLabel, HPos.RIGHT);

    TextField usernameField = new TextField();
    GridPane.setHalignment(usernameField, HPos.LEFT);

    mainPane.addRow(0, userLabel, usernameField);

    Label passwordLabel = new Label(PASSWORD_LABEL_TEXT);
    GridPane.setHalignment(passwordLabel, HPos.RIGHT);

    TextField passwordField = new TextField();
    GridPane.setHalignment(passwordField, HPos.LEFT);

    mainPane.addRow(1, passwordLabel, passwordField);

    HBox buttonPane = new HBox(BUTTON_PANE_SPACING);

    Button login = new Button(loginText);
    login.setPrefWidth(BUTTON_PREF_WIDTH);
    buttonPane.getChildren().add(login);
    login.setOnAction(e -> {
        username = usernameField.getText();
        password = passwordField.getText().toCharArray();
    });

    if (hasCancel) {
        Button cancel = new Button(CANCEL_TEXT);
        cancel.setPrefWidth(BUTTON_PREF_WIDTH);
        buttonPane.getChildren().add(cancel);
        cancel.setOnAction(e -> stage.close());
    }

    mainPane.add(buttonPane, 1, 2);
    GridPane.setHalignment(buttonPane, HPos.RIGHT);

    Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane);

    stage.setTitle(title);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setResizable(IS_RESIZABLE);
    stage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
        if (canClose) {
            stage.close();
        } else {
            e.consume();
        }
    });

    stage.showAndWait();

    return new UserInfo(username, password);
}
```

But when I call `showLoginPane()` I get:

[image: not working]

The buttons are supposed to be on the right, instead, I find it near the center, as if it is on the left side of its cell. Why is this happening? I am fairly new to JavaFX, but have some experience in Java.

**EDIT:**

It seems that `buttonPane` is taking up the whole space. If I add:

```
buttonPane.setStyle("-fx-border-color:blue;");
```

Then:

[image: Hmm...]

Now the problems is: How do you fix that?

Comment: I suspect the `buttonPane` is filling the entire second column, and then aligning the buttons to the left within its space (though the `buttonPane` itself is aligned to the right within its grid pane cell). You could set a border on it to check: `buttonPane.setStyle("-fx-border-color:blue;");`. Try `buttonPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);` If you refactor the code in your question as a [MCVE], I can give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either tell the `buttonPane` to align its contents to the right:

```
buttonPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
```

or you can tell the grid pane not to let the `buttonPane` grow with

```
GridPane.setFillWidth(buttonPane, false);
```